# How can I get a Canon MB2720 working in Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, canon

My Canon MG5520 recently died after several years of service. It worked perfectly under Linux via USB.

I went out and bought a Canon MB2720, and am unable to get it to do anything under Linux.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you looking for evidence that it is doing something? What do you see?

Comment: @benrudgers I have tried using the "Generic Drivers". When I try to print a test page, nothing happens. I also just tried the driver for the MB2390 (the closest model number). When I try to print a test page it says "Sending Fax" then does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

MB2320 has Linux drivers.  I don't know how similar the devices are though.

At this [link](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/small-office-home-office-printers/mb2320/maxify-mb2320) click on "Drivers and Downloads", then "Linux" in the drop down box, not "Linux 64 bit" or "Linux 32 bit".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!!

It's the [IJ Printer Driver Ver. 5.40](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/maxify_mb_series/maxify_mb2750.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1533036&os=Linux%20(32-bit)&language=EN) for Linux from Canon-Europe.

Just printed out the Ubuntu Test Page on my MB2720 and it looks good!!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Cannon has linux drivers with a debian-compatible installer here:

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/small-office-home-office-printers/mb2720/maxify-mb2720?tab=

Worked great for me. My last 3 printers have been Canon and they all supported linux.